# How to run wep page inside visual studio asp.net web application project with folder name having space

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, web-applications

I have created an asp.net core web application project and I want to view the `*.html` web page using the `View In browser` context menu. My webpage is inside a folder named `"finished exercises"`. I cannot open my webpage without removing the space in the folder name.

Is there any setting in Visual Studio to view the web page using the context menu without removing the space in the folder name?

[image]

If I replace folder name with `"finished_exercises"` it works fine

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no such configuration in Visual Studio. Although there is no specific document stating that the name of the folder cannot have spaces, it does not seem to recognize it. If you want to confirm its naming convention, you can ask the [product group](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report?entry=problem).